# SQL Server 2005: How to identify all tables referencing a specified table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table which I need to get rid of. But there are several tables in the database referencing this table. Before I remove it, I need to modify the columns in the referencing tables. How can I find out which tables are referencing the table I want to remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are defined as foreign keys to the database table you can use the command

```
sp_help TableName
```

and that will list all of the constraints.